# Drupal not sending confirmation emails

Tags: drupal

I am setting up a Drupal 6 site.

I am not getting confirmation emails that are sent out when a user registers. (They are not in a Spam or Junk folder. They never get sent.)

I *do* get emails sent from the general contact form.

I installed the module SMTP Mail to see if it would solve this. It sends out a test email, and I got that.

But Drupal is still not sending out the confirmation email.

I had MIME Mail module installed, so I uninstalled that just to see if that was a problem, but no luck.

I see lots of posts with this identical issue, and no one can provide a solution.

This is happening BOTH on my live server at godaddy and on my local server using WAMP.

HELP! I can not figure out how to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I had created an action that gets triggered when a new user registers that redirects them to a "Thank you for registering page."  When I went into my triggers, and deleted the redirection action, I received the confirmation email.

Now all I have to figure out is WHY that trigger is causing a problem!  But at least emails are coming through again!